# Opened washing machine door when it said it had finished and water came flooding out

Tags: washing-machine

The washing cycle had finished and I couldn't open the door but when I finally did all of the water came flooding out. Have I broken the washing machine? And how come it said it had finished but was still filled with water and didn't drain out? I wouldn't have opened the door if I had known it was filled with water
Please help- is the washing machine broken???

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Pretty clearly something's broken, if only that the door shouldn't be able to be jimmied open. What make/model is this? How did you know the cycle was done? Might you have lost power?

Comment: This is almost always a clogged drain or a failed pump. It's very common to be afflicted with both at the same time, since the clogged or restricted drain puts too much load on the drain pump and eventually ruins it.